# How to import a policy on BlackBerry Enterprise Server Express

Tags: blackberry

I'm very new to the BlackBerry world and yesterday i finished the deployment of the BES Express SP2 on my environment.

The problem is that after i activated my BB phone whit this BESX server, the Facebook and other applications are no longer able to synchronize the events and contacts from Facebook to My BB phone.

Doing some research on the subjet i discovered that BESX  SP2 does not include the policy: Disable Organizer Data Access for Social Networking Applications (older versions did)

I would like to import this policy which is Detailed on this BB KB [KB15535](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB15535).

So far none of the mentioned solutions on the KB worked for me.

It seams that BES express has the feature of importing Policies trimmed out.

**Questions:**

> 1) Is there any way to import this policy on BESX?
>   2) if it is not possible, what other alternatives do i
>   have to access my exchange emails,
>   contacts etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually called blackberry techincal support about this exact issue. You are not able to import polices into the newest Versions of BES Express but they're development team is currently making a fix for the Facebook issue. They are going to get in touch with me when it is done and I will let you know.

The only other solution in the meantime is to go back to an earlier version of BES Express or wait for the fix.

For Exchange you access the emails & Contacts through the OWA site on your browse but you won't be able to sync until they have the fix.
Chris

Comment: Thanks very much Chris, ill be waiting for the fix and it wold be grate if you post a link here so some poor soul would not have to go trough all this pain :)

Comment: As soon as I have it I will. They just followed up with me again today that its not ready yet but they will let me know when it is.

Comment: Any news about this?

Comment: A solution is still outstanding

Comment: Latest email
Thank you for contacting BlackBerry Customer Support.  We are pleased to assist you.

After further investigation of the issue you are experiencing, it has been determined that this is by design for BES Express. There is currently a Feature Enhancement request for this to possibly be implemented in a future release of BES Express.

You can continue to monitor this feature enhancement in the release notes of later releases...
Feature Plan ID - ER-BES-0001152
Currently the only option would be to upgrade to a full BlackBerry Enterprise Server version.